# Facebook RSS Feed displayed in Joomla

Tags: facebook, joomla, rss, joomla3.0

I am currently trying to implement an external rss feed module into a joomla page.

I am using the following syntax as for the rss feed:

```
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=ID_HERE&format=rss20
```

When I test the feed on this website : http://validator.w3.org/feed/? the feed is does not validate BUT is being found.

When I try to display this feed in Joomla i simply get a message containing the following in the frontend : "RSS feed not found"

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: You don't really have ID_HERE do you?

Comment: I replaced it with the correct ID of the facebook page i want to get the RSS. Dont worry ^^

Comment: Could it be that Facebook removed that feed? If you shared the *actual* URL that would help :)

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=358338081033139&format=rss20

Comment: This feed is being removed in a few weeks, so I don't recommend relying on it (ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_90_day_deprecations )

Comment: Oh .... got any reliable source of the "new" way to get a link for a feed ? or a script which i could implement manually in a blank module ? that way i could deal with the json response manually without relying on the joomla premade module